# How to detect if there is one or multiple pages in a glossaries entry's number list?

Tags: conditionals, glossaries

I'd like to be able to print e.g. "p. 1" if an acronym is only used on one page and e.g. "pp. 1, 2" if it is used on multiple pages. I have tried to define a new counter and use its value in the `ifthenelse` but I don't know where to hook up the incrementing code. There is probably a less complicated solution anyway... :)

The MWE below needs to be built with `pdflatex mwe.tex ; makeglossaries mwe ; pdflatex mwe.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    shortcuts,
]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{\begin{description}}{\end{description}}

    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}] ##3\glspostdescription \space \footnotesize (%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{1}{1}}{p}{pp}. ##5)%
    }
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{bt}{BT}{Bluetooth}
\newacronym{usb}{USB}{Universal Serial Bus}
\begin{document}

\ac{bt}
\ac{usb}
\clearpage
\ac{usb}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mylist]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a solution.

I've used the command `\IfSubStr*` from the [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package to see if inside the 5th argument we have the words "delimN" or "delimR" (in the number list, `\delimN` is a command that expands to `,`  and `\delimR` expands to `--`) which, with the help of a new `\if`, determines where to print `pp` and where to print `p`.

If "delimN" or "delimR" are not present, this means that we have only one page number in the number list.

Note that I've also put `\footnotesize` inside a group...

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newif\ifmulti

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{\begin{description}}{\end{description}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \multifalse%
        \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##5}}{delimN}{\multitrue}{\relax}%
        \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##5}}{delimR}{\multitrue}{\relax}%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}] ##3\glspostdescription \space {\footnotesize (%
        \ifmulti pp\else p\fi. ##5)}%
    }%
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{bt}{BT}{Bluetooth}
\newacronym{usb}{USB}{Universal Serial Bus}
\newacronym{sata}{SATA}{Serial Advanced Technology Attachment}
\begin{document}

\ac{bt}
\ac{usb}
\ac{sata}
\clearpage
\ac{usb}
\ac{sata}
\clearpage
\ac{sata}
\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mylist]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: this fails of course for number ranges (those include `\delimR`). i had the idea to count the characters instead (with `\StrLen`), but i can't get that to work at all

Comment: @stefanct You're right. I simply forgot about number ranges... Now it should be OK.

Comment: yes, that works, thank you. (I had no idea about `ifmulti` yet, but a simple if-then-if-then-else works (with a bit of redundancy) too). I would rather see a more elegant solution, but so far this is definitely the best answer ;)