# Passim instead of multiple pagenumbers in glossaries

Tags: glossaries, conditionals, book-design

I'm using `glossaries` while preparing a volumnous book. The standard setup of `glossaries`works well for me, with one exception. It is a glossary of foreign words and there are some glossary entries that occur throughout the book, for which I don't want to have all of the page numbers added. In stead, I want the page reference to read *passim*.

This is my first try at using conditionals, with the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150754/how-to-detect-if-there-is-one-or-multiple-pages-in-a-glossaries-entrys-number-l) as a starting point. Goal is that all pagenumbers are referenced if there are up to twelve pages and/or page-ranges to reference to, and if more, then to produce *passim* instead of page numbers.

This is my starting point, but here I already get *passim* with more than one page number, and also the single page numbers are not there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newif\ifmulti %replace with something like \ifmorethan{#}?

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{\begin{description}}{\end{description}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \multifalse%
        \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##5}}{delimN}{\multitrue}{\relax}%
        \IfSubStr*{\detokenize{##5}}{delimR}{\multitrue}{\relax}%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}] ##3\glspostdescription \space {%
        \ifmulti \emph{passim} \else \fi ##5}%
    }%
}

\makeglossaries

\glsaddkey
 {extra}
 {\relax}
 {\glsentryextra}
 {\Glsentryextra}
 {\glsextra}
 {\Glsextra}
 {\GLSextra}

\newglossaryentry{veda}
    {
        name=veda,
        description={Religious text with hymns to the gods. The Vedas consist of Sama Veda, Rig Veda, Yajur Veda and Atharva Veda},
        text=veda,
        plural=vedas,
        sort=veda
    }

\newglossaryentry{viparit}
    {
        name={vipar\={\i}t karna},
        description={Acting contrary to one’s own nature},
        text=viparit karna,
        extra={Vipar\={\i}t karna\={\i}},
        sort=viparit karna
    }

\newglossaryentry{wasiat}
    {
        name={wasiyat, wasiat},
        description={Precept, commandment},
        text=wasiat,
        extra=wasiyat,
        sort=wasiyat
    }

\begin{document}

\gls{veda}
\gls{viparit}
\glsextra{wasiat}
\newpage
\gls{viparit}
\glsextra{veda}
\newpage
\gls{veda}

\printglossary[toctitle=\mbox{Glossary of Foreign Words},style=mylist]

\end{document}
```

Follow-up question: would it be easier to add something to the few `\newglossaryentry` descriptions that it concerns, that would prevent those from using the numbers? I could just enter `, \emph{passim}` to the `description=` field, and then somehow switch off the pagenumber references for that one particular entry?